# Are all line integrals zero by divergence theorem?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

Suppose there is a vector  field A.  Now the line integral over some curve c equals double integration of curl A over surface S enclosed by C. Now if we put the divergence theorem in this then it becomes  triple integral of divergence of curl Adv over the volume enclosed by  the surface. Now divergence of curl of vector A becomes zero.  Now so the volume integral should be zero. So the surface and line integral is also zero. So we can do this for any line integral (where the vector is defined in the surface). So does it imply all line integrals are zero. Where am I doing the mistake? Sorry for mathjax.

Comment: What are the hypotheses on using the divergence theorem?

Comment: @JasonDeVito the vector should be valid throughout the region. The surface should enclose a volume. The region has to be simply connected.

Comment: If the surface encloses a volume, does it have a boundary curve?

Comment: @JasonDeVito it should have a plane not a curve I guess. Except sphere or paraboloid etc.

Comment: Nope, no exceptions.  If a surface encloses a volume, it has no boundary curve.  So there is no way to apply the divergence theorem after applying Stokes's theorem

Comment: @JasonDeVito thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want, you can write your own answer.  I don't need the rep points.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I don't take the things which other deserve.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to apply the divergence theorem, your surface $S$ needs to enclose a solid.  This, in particular, implies that $S$ itself has no boundary.  But using Stokes's theorem relates the integral over a surface to an integral over its boundary.  Thus, there is no surface $S$ for which both theorems apply.